# How to ban client ip adress with django-axes instead of the local ip address of the angular server from which the login request is transmitted?

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, angular7

I use django-rest-framework as a back-end and Angular 7 as a front-end. I wanted to secure my login page by limiting the login attempts and I did so with django-axes. The problem is that the login request are transmitted from the angular server to the django server with the rest framework, thus the login attempts are all displayed as coming from 127.0.0.1 which is the login ip address of my Angular server.

For the time being, I had to enable only username based ban, but this is quite restricted.

Is there any way to transmit the actual ip address to django-axes for it to be banned? Or is there anything better than django-axes that I could use to solve this?